# EKEvent.notes returns (null) even when EKEvent.hasNotes returns YES

Tags: ios

I'm on Xcode 6.0.1, making a test app with Event Kit. The following code successfully populates each event's title, but its notes are returned as (null) even when hasNotes property returns YES. And, I can see the notes for the same event on iPhone's default calendar app.

What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent
                               completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                       if (error)
                                       {
                                           NSLog(@" !! error");
                                           // display error message here
                                       }
                                       else if (!granted)
                                       {
                                           NSLog(@"Not Granted");
                                           // display access denied error message here
                                       }
                                       else
                                       {
                                           // access granted

                                           NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
                                           // Create the start date components
                                           NSDateComponents *oneWeekAgoComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
                                           oneWeekAgoComponents.day = -1;
                                           NSDate *oneWeekAgo = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneWeekAgoComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
                                           // Create the end date components
                                           NSDateComponents *oneMonthFromNowComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
                                           oneMonthFromNowComponents.month = 1;
                                           NSDate *oneMonthFromNow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneMonthFromNowComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

                                           // Create the predicate from the event store's instance method
                                           NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:oneWeekAgo endDate:oneMonthFromNow calendars:nil];
                                           // Fetch all events that match the predicate
                                           _eventArray = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

                                           [self.tableView reloadData];

                                       }
                                   });
                               }];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    EKEvent *event = [self.eventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = event.title;

    if (event.hasNotes) {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = event.notes;
    } else {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't fully resolved it, but got a clue.

```
NSArray *events = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
```

This didn't get the notes. So, instead I enumerate through returned events by doing

```
 [eventStore enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:predicate usingBlock:^(EKEvent *event, BOOL *stop) {
                                               NSLog(@"title: %@",event.title);
                                               NSLog(@"hasNotes: %s",event.hasNotes ? "YES":"NO");
                                               NSLog(@"notes: %@",event.notes);
                                               NSLog(@"-----");
                                               [_eventTitles addObject:event.title];
                                               [_eventTitles addObject:event.hasNotes ? event.notes : @""];
                                           }];
```

This one returns actual notes (null).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue like this but when accessing the calendar object from the `EKEvent`. I my case this was because I had released the `EKEventStore` instance before I attempted to access the calendar (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`).

According to the Apple documentation "Reading and Writing Calendar Events":

> An event store instance must not be released before other Event Kit
>   objects; otherwise, undefined behavior may occur.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004775-SW1